# java generated pdf android download

Tags: java, android, pdf, download, generated

I'm sending data through POST to a java file that generates a pdf and outputs:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
```

When I try this on an android device, it downloads a blank pdf rather than displaying it in a browser tab like it does on iPad and on the desktop.

Does anyone know of a solution to this?

-Chris

Comment: Embed the pdf inside an html page.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick, easy, to the point and doesn't require any third-party script:

```
<embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

See more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)